# LINQ combine select and update query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a LINQ database operation that looks like this:

```
using (SomeDC TheDC = new SomeDC())
{   
    var SomeData = (from .... select x).ToList();

    if (SomeData.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (.... in SomeData) { x.SomeProp = NewProp; }

        TheDC.SubmitChanges();  
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm reading a list, then I'm updating this list, and finally I'm writing it back to the DB. Is there a way to combine this operation in just one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to combine this operation in just one query?

Not in Linq - you could execute one SQL statement directly if there's a pattern to the updates, but querying and updating are two separate methods.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should keep using a simple loop to manipulate your objects.There is no method for updating in `LINQ`.As the name suggests: *Language Integrated **Query***,  `LINQ` used for querying not for updating.

You could manually generate the sql query for your update operation then execute it via [`SqlQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method or you can also execute [`Stored Procedures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx) with Entity Framework if you wish.

Comment: +1, but `Count()` just calls `Count` if the underlying collection is a `List` (technically _any_ `ICollection`).  Using `Any` _would_ be an improvement, however.

Comment: Wouldn't `Any` be a better test, albeit it's not even needed as the foreach wouldn't execute

Comment: @BobVale If the underlying enumerable didn't implement `ICollection`, then yes, but since it does, no, not really; at least not enough to matter.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a single update select statement, however you could shorten your code and drop the `ToList()` call.

Additionally the check of count is unnecessary as the foreach wouldn't operate for an empty loop anyhow.

```
using (SomeDC TheDC = new SomeDC())
{   
    var SomeData = (from .... select x);
    foreach (.... in SomeData) { x.SomeProp = NewProp; }
    TheDC.SubmitChanges();  
}
```

Alternatively if you are desperate to just do it in a single execute you can roll your own extension method to help.

```
public static class DatabaseHelper {

  public static void Apply<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Action<T> action) {
     if (collection == null) { // Sanity check
        return;
     }
     foreach (var item in collection) {
        action(item);
     }
  }
}
```

Then your code would be

```
using (SomeDC TheDC = new SomeDC()) {
  (from ... select x).Apply(x => x.SomeProp = NewProp);
  TheDC.SubmitChanges();
}
```